# Not all voice files give output from Google Speech to Text API for Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-speech-api

I am using below Node.js script snippet,

```
'use strict';
var google_speech = require('google-speech');
google_speech.ASR({
    debug: true,
    lang: 'en_US',
    developer_key: '<Google API Key>',
    file: '<voice file name with path>',
  }, function(err, httpResponse, xml){   
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log(httpResponse.statusCode, xml)
      }
    }
);
```

The output I am getting from some audio files but not for all. Even for example one `flac` file is giving output but another `flac` file doesn't.

Is there any specific type of files are required for this API to give output. If yes, then let me know the specific type/format of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [this google-speech](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-speech) Node library, it appears that it's hardcoded the `content-type` header to `audio/l16; rate=16000` [here](https://github.com/antirek/google-speech/blob/master/lib/GoogleASR.js#L19) in the source code.

It looks like this can be overridden as an option in your first param, so, for example, if you're using a 44.1khz flac file, the following might work

```
'use strict';
var google_speech = require('google-speech');
google_speech.ASR({
    debug: true,
    lang: 'en_US',
    developer_key: '<Google API Key>',
    file: '<voice file name with path>',
    'content-type': 'audio/x-flac; rate=44100' // ← override it here
  }, function(err, httpResponse, xml){   
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log(httpResponse.statusCode, xml)
      }
    }
);
```

That being said (and this wasn't what you asked), it does appear that Google's recently updated their official [Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/), which you may also find useful. They've got a nodejs tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/rest-tutorial), and more extensive details [about the file formats supported here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/best-practices#audio_encoding).